# Changing nested buttons values

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have nested record that I reinsert into a another table by ajax,
when I submit data I have a  script that changes the button message to "Sent" when  form is sent. Now the script I think only works for only one record but not nested records, because when the records from the db are populated and I click on the first button it changes, but doesn't when I start clicking from the second button downwards.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $('input:submit', 'form').click(function(){
        $(this).val('Sent');
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
</script>
```

ajax insert

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();    
        data = $(this).serialize();    
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {      
            $("input[type=text]").val("");    
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: attach the `onclick` listener to the new elements?

Comment: how? i'm new with ajax

Comment: try call your `.click` function again in the `onsuccess` callback

Answer (score 0):

When you run something like `$('input:submit', 'form')` it creates a jQuery collection with the items that exist at that time. If you add new elements later, they don't get appended to existing variables (which is a good idea).

You can either re-run the binding code when you add new items or use event delegation on a top level element that exists from the beginning.

Comment: please can you phrase it into my code. cos i'm not that good in jquery